# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I have following function

```
function getQuery($sql,$returnType = ''){
    $data = array();
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($result){
        switch($returnType){
            case 'count':
                $data = $result->num_rows;
                break;
            case 'single':
                $data = $result->fetch_assoc();  //Line 55
                break;
            default:
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        $data[] = $row;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    if(!empty($data)) {
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When this method is executed following error is returned

> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()
>
> Line Number: 55

I can't understand why the error is being shown. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch_assoc()` is not a method of Codeignetor query builder it's actaullay method of `mysqli`  but you are use "Codeignetor query builder"

for single row use like

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

$row = $query->row();

if (isset($row))
{
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->body;
}
```

for multiple row :

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['body'];
}
```

You have to use Below Code

```
function getQuery($sql,$returnType = ''){
    $data = array();
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($result){
        switch($returnType){
            case 'count':
                $data = $result->num_rows();
                break;
            case 'single':
                $data = $result->row_array(); // return result as array
                 or
                $data = $result->row(); //  return result as object
                break;
            default:
                $data = $result->result_array(); // result in array
                or
                $data =  $result->result(); // return a objects
        }
    }
    if(!empty($data)) {
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error

Comment: I am trying to use it as foreach($info['options'] as $opt)

Comment: hello Amaan plz refer the https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html you got some basic idea how it's work

Comment: I have the basic idea but I just want to ask how can I use this line with a 2D array

Comment: Here I just want to extract the column_value corresponding to the row value 'options'

Comment: print $info['options']  and check what it returns

Comment: do one thing use var_dump($info) and check it's returning any aaray or object

Comment: And print or echo is returning nothing

Comment: var_dump($info) is returning an array

Comment: Is there 'options' index in info array.If yes is it empty ?

Comment: your option index should also contain array in this case. other wise it is blank. and you need to check empty condition

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

```
function getQuery($sql,$returnType = ''){
    $data = array();
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($result){
        switch($returnType){
            case 'count':
                $data = $result->num_rows;
                break;
            case 'single':
                $data = $result->row();  // CodeIgniter return single row 
                break;
            default:
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    $data = $result->result(); // CodeIgniter return result object and you can set result_array() get array list
                }
        }
    }
    if(!empty($data)) {
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Now its displaying : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: How can I access a field inside $data

Comment: Nikunj code return a object so you can access for single row $data->first_name it's just exmaple

Comment: yes you can access single row after **$data->first_name.**